# Check if a string with comma separated values contains given number using regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a regex to check whether a given number is included or not in a string containing numbers separated by comma. For eg
Check if 1 is in 
'1,2,3,4' - ans yes
'2,13,4' - ans no
"1"- ans yes
How can this be done using regex. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Use word boundaries `\b1\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word boundaries would be usefull

```
\b1\b
```

This ensures that the number is presceded and followed by a word boundary

- `\b` assert position at a word boundary. `,` is included in the word boundaries

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fK7bB8/1)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the solution, I'd like to choose all of you as answered, but choosing what I found very useful information